# Ultrasonic flow sensor

Tags: ultrasonic-sensors

The goal is to have a non-invasive flow meter that I can clamp over hydraulic lines.

As a student of hydraulics, I ended up looking and poking around for a good way to make an ultrasonic flow sensor with Arduino and possibly the hc-sr04. Not married to either idea.

So, I admit, I know nothing, but is it possible to do this?
Is there an easier way?

Comment: The HC-SR04's ultrasonics are sound waves in air and might not couple well into a hydraulic line without some special adapters

Comment: Thanks, I know my post wasnt that specific. I'm mostly looking for just a general starting point. The biggest one being, which ultrasonic detectors are applicable. I don't know much of anything about this, but wanted to see what info was out there.

Comment: I'm going to migrate this question to robotics as it's more relevant there.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Yippeethemagician, but this is looking like a shopping question. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see & what you actually saw. Take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Please work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) & edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Your other question has just been brought to my attention, so as that one is better phrased, I have closed this as a duplicate of it.